# Block access to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

Let's say I have a JavaScript file... using .htaccess is there a way I can make it so a user can NOT look inside the JavaScript file?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that user can still open developer tools and see the source code there, in either network tab or in source tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !http://your-domain\.com/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*js$ - [F]
```

This will return 403 code (forbidden) when referer is outside your domain for all JavaScript files.

**NOTE**: But this solution will only make access to the file harder. If someone will want to see the file, he will do that eventually. Because you can't fully block the js files, if the browser can read it, the user also will. Example: you only can open dev tools and you will see the source. Or if someone will figure out that the block is by referrer he can create link to file or use other way to add the header to the request.

Comment: But after block by .htaccess then my own site can't be load js file or access it. so how to resolve it? please tell me. i also want do like that. anyuser don't seen or access my file by browser but my domain use it my script tag

Comment: @HarsukhMakwana the referer part should make it load your js file if it's in script tag but not when you open it in new tab because it will not have the referer, to open it in new tab you can crate a link `<a href="file.js" target="_blank">click</a>` and click on it. Also you need to put same domain as the one you store your files on. Also https http matter if you have http in .htacceess and you open page on https it also will not work.

Comment: Can you help me ? because i have been try to done like that last 3 days. i explain my issue in details. can i send message on your hangout? harsukh21@gmai.com is mine ID. please help me if you can

Comment: @HarsukhMakwana you can create anther question with link to this one and solution that didn't work. If you will have question more people may help.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can obfuscate it or hide the javascript inside another container (like inline in your page), but not prevent them looking at it.

If you block it with your htaccess file, then the browser will not be able to download it and use it, which makes it pointless having the javascript file. Once downloaded by the browser it sits in the cache on the local machine, so a determined/knowledgeable person can find it and inspect it. If you obfuscate it you will make it very hard for the user to comprehend it, so maybe that is the best option.

Comment: How good would obfuscate it do... like I just don't want them reading the Javasript file... but if it's all garbaged up.. ti would work.

Comment: Why don't you want them to be able to read it?  What function does this javascript file perform that it needs to be hidden?

Comment: What I mean is that would anyone be able to UNDO my obsufate to my code?

Comment: Yes, sure, if they are willing to spend enough time. So if your algorithms are so good that you don't want to share them with anybody, keep them on the server and provide a proper interface to them. De-obfuscating code that is not meant to be public can be fun. :) That is, de-obfuscating would not be possible for *anyone*, only for *someone*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://dean.edwards.name/packer/
 Check the `Base62 encode` and `Shrink variables` boxes to make the JS code hard to read.

Then you have Yahoo compressor: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/
And the Google compressor: http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

The first one is on-line, the 2 last ones need some installation on your machine.

But... as the browser needs to understand the javascript it receives, a patient and decided person will be able to reverse engineer it. But the compressors above will discourage many of them.

Comment: Here's an idea. A PHP include going to a PHP file and inside THAT would be a include to the Javascript file!

Comment: Also! I can compress the code twice.. once in one compress and take THAT code into ANOTHER!

Comment: @Dan, then I go to my browser and type the url of your first PHP page, and I get the js ;) Don't loose too much time on that. In the end the source is coming as javascript to the browser and you have to live with that.

Comment: WEll I don't know if they can RUN the JavaScript - I just don't want them to know whats in it.

Comment: In our web app, for efficiency and to have a single http call we compress everything in one html page. HTML+JS+CSS. This make the page a long string of ~300kb, I dare anyone to try to read it and understand. Although it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make your javascript more-or-less "difficult" to read is by compressing and obfuscating it.

Here are some solutions:

- [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)
- [Online Javascript Compressor](http://javascriptcompressor.com/)

Answer (score 1):

This is really a pointless exercise. If somebody can run your Javascript on your site, he can run it anywhere else he likes and make any changes he wants. This has not proven to be a very big problem in the history of the Web, so I wouldn't waste much time on it.

If it's really that big of a worry that somebody will "steal" your Javascript, copyright is your best weapon. If some algorithm is secret, do the processing on the server and just provide the result.

Comment: Oh, how would I do that? I Am interesting in the server-side processing :)

Comment: @Dan: Have a script (PHP, Ruby, Java — it doesn't matter) on your site that your Javascript calls to with AJAX, providing the input of the algorithm and getting back the output.

Comment: That sounds too complicated (even though I know Java and PHP) haha.

Comment: I Agree, Using ***Developer Tools on Google Chrome*** for Example:
**Click on Resources > Your Site > Scripts > filename.js**
And it will appear right there Crystal Clear.

Answer (score 1):

**You Can't Really Protect Your Javascript Files**

---

Using ***Developer Tools on Google Chrome***:

**Click on Resources > Your Site > Scripts > filename.js**

And it will appear right there Crystal Clear.