# How to prevent website being grabbed by IDM( or anyother webstie grabber)?Is there any way to prevent it?

Tags: security

Using website grabbers whole website with folder structure can be downloaded.
Is there any way to prevent this?
If so,how?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to protect a websites markup is not to publish it. If you want your users to see something they need to get the HTML markup and the images, that should be displayed. And therefore the files need to be accessible. And if your files are accessible every user/bot/crawler/grabber can save these files.

Comment: hmmm....but cant we prevent the css,javascript,images with folder structure from downloading? I have heared there are someways to do it by making changes in .htaccess file but dont know the details..

Comment: the only way of fully hiding your folder structure is to inline everything in the html file you're sending to the users. You can however deny direct access to the files if the user comes form another domain via .htaccess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672133/block-access-to-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to put a few files like the index page in the main directory and call the other sub pages in it. If using php then you may do the following.

Say keep the index.php in the main folder and keep the homepage.php in a directory called includes and use the homepage in the index.php via include function in php.

Now add a .htaccess file to the includes folder which must contain
"deny from all"

This way users can use the page but will not have direct access to the files. So will be for the grabber.